# MongoDB - Concatenating two properties in a model and updating the model with the result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to concatenate two things in this model.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
let file= new File({
    name: req.body.name,
    year: req.body.year,
    code: req.body.code
});
file.save().then(data => {
    res.send(data);
}, err => {
    res.send(err);
})});
```

So what I want to do is that I want to take the input from the user for name and year, and once the post request goes through I want to take name+'_'+ Last six characters of MongoDB object ID and update the model and patch code with the result. How am I able to achieve this in an efficient way? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Sample doc

```
{ "_id": { "$oid": "5aa420c2f92b4d77fc342e62" }, "name": "n", "year": "1992", "code": "", "__v": 0 }
```

Sample output for the field "code" from above document.

> "code": "n_342e62"

The code should update after the post request by itself by concatenating those two properties.

Comment: show a sample document

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5aa420c2f92b4d77fc342e62"
    },
    "name": "n",
    "year": "1992",
    "code": "",
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: And the what's the sample input/output you are looking for?

Comment: { "_id": { "$oid": "5aa420c2f92b4d77fc342e62" }, "name": "n", "year": "1992", "code": "n_342e62", "__v": 0 }
The code should update after the post request by itself by concatenating those two properties.

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the use of creating this code? Also there isn't a "trigger" feature which would automatically update this field on insert.

Comment: Can we not use another save inside the post request once the previous properties needed have been posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you would want to do it only *after* the `post` request has been finished. But here is how you can do it:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
let file= new File({
    name: req.body.name,
    year: req.body.year,
    code: req.body.code
});
file.save().then(data => {
    res.send(data);

    //after the DATA has been sent, you can save the code
    let id = data._id.toString();
    data.code = data.name + "_" + id.slice(id.length - 6, id.length);
    data.save();
}, err => {
    res.send(err);
})});
```

(Also, Please clarify whether you want to take the `name` or the `year` for the code).

Answer (score 0):

try this, Generate mongo Id before saving data.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const body = req.body;
    let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    body._id = id;
    id = id.toString();
    let file = new File();
    data.code = `${data.name}_${id.substr(id.length - 6)}`;
    file = Object.assign(file, body);
    const data = await file.save();
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send('Something went wrong');
  }
});
```